How do I add GZIP support to a REST client in OpenLiberty using RESTEasy?
Regarding GZIP compression and decompression, the client-side configuration, as mentioned in [1], requires registering the following to enable GZIP support:

org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPEncodingInterceptor
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.AcceptEncodingGZIPFilter

As far as I understand, OpenLiberty ships with RESTEasy, so the dependency on org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core is set to provided scope. However, when deploying to OpenLiberty version 24.0.0.9, an exception was thrown:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/GZIPDecodingInterceptor
I then tried adding the apiTypeVisibility with value as spec, ibm-api, api, stable, third-party to classloader, but the NoClassDefFoundError still occurs.
Next, I added the dependency on org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core with the compile scope, which resolved the NoClassDefFoundError, but introduced other exceptions.
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: 
    "java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation 
    for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl: 
    when selecting overriding method 'org.jboss.resteasy.spi.statistics.StatisticsController 
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl.getStatisticsController()' 

    the class loader com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader @375d646a 
    of the selected method's type 
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl, 
    and the class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @763d3eb8 for its super type 
    org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory have different Class objects for the type 
    org.jboss.resteasy.spi.statistics.StatisticsController used in the signature 

    (org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl is in unnamed module of loader
    com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader @375d646a, 
    parent loader com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.GatewayClassLoader @31b2fab3; 
    org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory is in unnamed module of loader 
    org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @763d3eb8, parent loader 
    com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader @4988d8b8) 
    com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init 111" at ffdc_24.10.04_11.47.21.0.log

[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "jakarta.servlet.ServletException: 
    Filter [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.Filter30Dispatcher]: could not be initialized 
   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter 380" at ffdc_24.10.04_11.47.21.1.log

[ERROR   ] SRVE0321E: The [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.Filter30Dispatcher] 
    filter did not load during start up.

Filter [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.Filter30Dispatcher]: could not be initialized

Could you please advise on how to add GZIP support to a REST client in OpenLiberty using RESTEasy?
[1] https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.10.Final/userguide/#_gzip_compressiondecompression
